# Setting value of Select in html

Tags: python, html

I am generating this html from python and 2% is the value of the field so it is what should be shown but I am baffled as to why it doesn't work as I expect. I have tried so many permutations and figure it is something so simple.   Please Help.  I don't necessarily want to use the selected option in the `<option>` tag.

```
    <select name="discount" value="2%">
       <option>10%</option>
       <option>9%</option>
       <option>8%</option>
       <option>7%</option>
       <option>6%</option>
       <option>5%</option>
       <option>4%</option>
       <option>3%</option>
       <option>2%</option>
       <option>1%</option>
       <option">0%</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: means '2%' is not showing as an option in the dropdown ?

Comment: The 2% option is showing but it is not showing as the selected item

Comment: ok sure you may look to my answer, i have a suggesstion

Answer (score 2):

If you want to selected 2% value then your dropdown should be like this :

```
<select name="discount">
       <option value="10%">10%</option>
       <option value="9%">9%</option>
       <option value="8%">8%</option>
       <option value="7%">7%</option>
       <option value="6%">6%</option>
       <option value="5%">5%</option>
       <option value="4%">4%</option>
       <option value="3%">3%</option>
       <option selected value="2%">2%</option>
       <option value="1%">1%</option>
       <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
```

try with it.

Comment: This does work but not easy to code as python generated code

Comment: Hello Dear.. Actually i m not familiar with python. But in basic if you want to selected 2% then you should put if condition land selected it. As in e.g of i would try this in form as :  <option <?php if(isset($val)){ echo "selected";} ?> value="%2">%2</option>

Answer (score 1):

Are you mean this? put your value on `<option>`, not `<select>`. And see whats double quote on last `<option>`

```
    <select name="discount">
       <option value="10%">10%</option>
       <option value="9%">9%</option>
       <option value="8%">8%</option>
       <option value="7%">7%</option>
       <option value="6%">6%</option>
       <option value="5%">5%</option>
       <option value="4%">4%</option>
       <option value="3%">3%</option>
       <option value="2%">2%</option>
       <option value="1%">1%</option>
       <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Sorry I did fix that quote in my code.   it is as you stated

Comment: What i want is the 2% to be the selected item

Answer (score 1):

Add a selected attribute to the item. You also had a stray quotation mark on the last `<option>`

```
<select name="discount">
    <option>10%</option>
    <option>9%</option>
    <option>8%</option>
    <option>7%</option>
    <option>6%</option>
    <option>5%</option>
    <option>4%</option>
    <option>3%</option>
    <option selected>2%</option>
    <option>1%</option>
    <option>0%</option>
</select>
```

**Alternatively you can use JavaScript to set the option:**

```
document.getElementsByName('discount')[0].selectedIndex = 8
```

**or as you've suggested in the comments if all values are unique you may be able to just set the value** the only caveat to this method is if two options have the same value but different text the incorrect option may be selected

```
document.getElementsByName('discount')[0].value = "2%"
```

Either of these scripts should be able to be run inlined anywhere after the select box or onload.

Comment: brian you have to add 8 spaces to the front of  your source

Comment: Sorry it pasted weird - I've corrected the formatting

Comment: Yes this works but this is code generated by a python script and not easy to generate in this manner.

Comment: Would it be viable to set it via JS? You could set the selectedIndex property of the select box - 

`document.getElementsByName('discount')[0].selectedIndex = 8`

Comment: <body onload="myfield=document.getElementsByName('discount')[0].value='2%'">

Comment: Glad to hear, I'll update the answer with the JS snippet - either snippet should also work inlined anywhere after the select box - if you'd like to avoid adding clutter to your body tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Description** Use the following HTML for your query.

```
     <select name="discount">
        <option value="10%">10%</option>
        <option value="9%">9%</option>
        <option value="8%">8%</option>
        <option value="7%">7%</option>
        <option value="6%">6%</option>
        <option value="5%">5%</option>
        <option value="4%">4%</option>
        <option value="3%">3%</option>
        <option value="2%" selected>2%</option>
        <option value="1%">1%</option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: My html is generated by python and is not easy to generate in this format.

Comment: so can you place the python code in your question, so i can generate this for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me and thanks to Brian

```
    <body onload="myfield=document.getElementsByName('discount')[0].value='2%'">
    <select name="discount">
        <option value="10%">10%</option>
        <option value="9%">9%</option>
        <option value="8%">8%</option>
        <option value="7%">7%</option>
        <option value="6%">6%</option>
        <option value="5%">5%</option>
        <option value="4%">4%</option>
        <option value="3%">3%</option>
        <option value="2%">2%</option>
        <option value="1%">1%</option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
```